# Include cria espaço no Layout do site

Tags: php, include

Tenho duas paginas. Uma index.php e a outra se chama menu.php.

Como o menu é o mesmo e repito ele em varias pagina preferi fazer ele em um documento separado e depois adicionar ele com o `include ("menu.php")`. Só que sempre que uso isso fica um espaço, como na imagem a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se eu adiciono mais *include* o espaço se repete, vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando olho o código fonte fica umas paradas estranhas uns *"        "* que nem sei da onde veio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu poderia inserir o *trecho do código* aqui porem esse problema só tenho quando uso o include, agora se eu montar toda estrutura da index.php numa mesma pagina esse problema não acontece.

código da pagina index.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<!-- Meta Tags -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<!-- Scripts -->
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
    <body>

        <!-- Google analitycs -->
        <?php include_once("includes/analyticstracking.php") ?>

        <!-- Menu -->
        <?php include_once("includes/menu.php") ?>

    </body>
</html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/geral.css">
```

codigo do menu.php

```
<div class="men">

</div>
```

codigo do geral.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Padrão Geral */
@font-face {font-family: NFO;font-style: normal; font-weight: normal; src: url(../fonte/fonte.woff); }
a{text-decoration:none; color:inherit}
*{font-family:NFO; margin:0px; padding:0px  }
body{background-color:#f4f4f4}

/* Pagina Index */

    /* Menu */
        .men{width:100%; height:60px; background-color:#2f2f2f; float:left}
```

Comment: Eu testei aqui e esta normal. pode ser alguma configuração do apache.

Comment: li sobre o problema. O problema é que dependendo do sistema operacional, ao incluir um arquivo php em outro arquivo php, o próprio arquivo criar caracteres invisíveis, e esses caracteres são interpretados pelo browser gerando esse espaço no layout. Assim que eu achar uma resposta que realmente seja útil eu publico aqui.

Comment: Já tentou no seu código CSS: `html,body {margin:0;padding:0;}` e ver os resultados?

Comment: Poderia disponibilizar o código completo do menu.php e do analyticstracking.php ?

Comment: Cara, essa pergunta merece todos os méritos, pois muita gente já quebrou a cabeça com isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse tipo de problema também costuma acontecer por causa da codificação dos documentos.

Experimente abrir os arquivos utilizados com o **Notepad++** e converter para **UTF-8 sem BOM**, escolhendo a opção abaixo

[image: Selecione "Converter para UTF-8(sem BOM)]

Basta clicar na aba "Formatar" para abrir essa opção

Comment: rssrrsrs, Quando dei essa resposta, nem tinha imaginado que ela seria tão útil! Mas trata-se de um problema semelhante que aconteceu comigo (quebrei muito a cabeça!)

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a resposta em inglês nesse link aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549445/utf8-without-bom-encoding-in-eclipse

> I found it easier to use Edit->Set Encoding. Set it to ISO, delete the characters, save, set it back to UTF-8. No need to close and reopen the file

Ao configurar a codificação para ISO surgem alguns caracteres bem no início da página. Basta apagá-los e configurar de novo para UTF-8.

Facilita pra quem usa eclipse, funcionou perfeitamente comigo.