# Por que o pseudo-element '::first-letter' não funciona corretamente neste exemplo?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ao utilizá-lo, surge um espaço no fim da página, fazendo com que o 'footer' suba um pouco. Isso não acontece quando se usa 'first-line', por exemplo. É só com 'first-letter'.

Alguém saberia me explicar por que isso acontece e como resolver o problema?

Edit -- Testado somente no Firefox.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByWQaK

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você testou isso em qual navegador? Olhei aqui no Chrome e não aconteceu isso que você descreveu.

Comment: Tem como você tirar um print das duas situações? Não estou conseguindo reproduzir este problema aqui (ou não estou vendo)

Comment: Eu confirmo que em Firefox, versão 34 a correr em Linux, com o uso do pseudo-selector `::first-letter` ou `:first-letter` no fundo da página fica um espaço considerável, espaço esse que não aparece quando essa declaração de CSS se encontra comentada.

Comment: Funcionou normalmente no Google Chrome.

Comment: Dá uma olhada pra ver se isso te ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43323/include-cria-espa%C3%A7o-no-layout-do-site/43445#43445

Comment: Obrigado, @Zuul . É possível assumir, então,  que isso seja um bug do Firefox? Estranho é que, aparentemente, o mesmo problema não se reproduziu com o André Ribeiro .

Comment: @WallaceMaxters , obrigado. infelizmente não consegui fazer uma comparação entre o meu problema e a pergunta do link que vc enviou. E ao que parece, tal problema não ocorre no Chrome.